# get the size of the html table dynamically in a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I would like to get the size of a html table in a php variable
Here is my table

```
 <table  align="center" class="table table-bordered"id="tb" border="10" bordercolor="#0066FF" style=\"background-color:#CCFFFF\" width="50%" cellpadding="9" cellspacing="9">
    <tr><b>
    <td colspan="3">Empid</td>
    <td colspan="3">Name</td>
    <td colspan="3">Email ID</td>
    <td colspan="3">Nominated and invited</td>
    <td colspan="3">Attendance</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addrow" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
    </b></tr>

        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
          {?>

          <tr>
         <td colspan="3" class="table-active"><input readonly name="emp_code[]" id="emp_code[]" value="<?php echo $row['emp_code']?>"class="form-control"></td>
          <td colspan="3" class="table-success"><input readonly name="emp_name[]" id="emp_name[]"value="<?php echo $row['emp_name']?>"class="form-control"></td>
          <td colspan="3" class="table-info"><input readonly name="emp_mailid[]" id="emp_mailid[]" value="<?php echo $row['emp_mailid']?>"class="form-control"></td>
          <td colspan="3" class="table-info"><input readonly name="nomination[]" id="nomination[]" value="<?php echo $row['nomination']?>"class="form-control"></td>
           <td colspan="3" class="table-info">
           <input type="checkbox"  id="attendance[]" name="attendance[]" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></td>
          <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='disabled'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
         <?php }?>
         </td>
         </tr>

         </table>
```

When I click on function `addrow()` a new row will be added sameway when i click on remove a row will be deleted.

```
 <script>
    jQuery(function() {
      var counter = 1;
      jQuery('a.addrow').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td colspan="3" class="table-active"><input type="text" name="emp_code[]" id="emp_code[]"  class="form-control"></td><td colspan="3" class="table-success"><input type="text" name="emp_name[]" id="emp_name[]" class="form-control"></td><td colspan="3" class="table-info"><input type="text" name="emp_mailid[]" id="emp_mailid[]" class="form-control"></td><td colspan="3" class="table-info"><input type="text" name="nomination[]" id="nomination[]" class="form-control"></td><td colspan="3"><input type="checkbox" class="toggleone" name="attendance[]" id="attendance[]" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td></tr>');
        counter++;
        jQuery('table.table').append(newRow);
      //Init bootstrapToggle
      $('.toggleone').bootstrapToggle({
        on: 'Yes',
        off: 'No'
      });
      });
    });   
    </script>
```

Here is my remove function

```
    <script>
$(function(){

     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
           }
      });
});  
</script>
```

Finally i need to find the length of the table i.e number of rows in a php variable.
Someone help me to do this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you want to store the value? Would it be enough to keep the "size" updated in a data attribute you can query when needed? Is your issue how to obtain the row count using jquery or how to post it to your server?

Comment: You can get row count by [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/a8mJP/1/). then you can call ajax to save that rows to your server.

Comment: incrase by one in the loop where you add rows?

Comment: I wanna store the number of rows in a php variable and use that further in a for loop